# How to match ,  in match in Racket?

Tags: scheme, racket

if I have something like this 
`(define s (hi,there))`
then how can I write in match
like
`(match s [(,h , ,t)] ...)`
But it is not working, because `match` needs the `,` so how can I do this?

Comment: Forgive the unsolicited comment, but it appears to me that using racket's 'match' to parse input that contains commas is probably not a great idea; unless the rest of the input is really very very close to racket/LISP, this sounds like a case for biting the bullet and using an actual parser. Apologies in advance if I've misunderstood your use case.

Comment: @JohnClements I think you are right..  and the story is that my main program is written in Racket and I just want to get the data structures built up from parsing the file in Racket. The file almost looks like S-Exp, then until very late, I found there were commas...

Comment: Do you have any kind of specification for what forms can occur in the source file? Is the source file written in some well-known language?

Comment: @JohnClements Nope, no specification of the forms of the files from third party...they are just text. Maybe I could use sed or awk to parse the text, or use any language to parse files line by line, but just thought the `read` in racket can just read them in and for every `(something)`, I can easily extract some fields, then encounter the comma problem:)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First note that the comma `,` is a special reader abbreviation.
The `(hi,there)` is a read as `(hi (unquote there))`. This is
difficult to spot - since the default printer prints lists
whose first element is an `unquote` in a special way.

```
Welcome to DrRacket, version 5.3.0.14--2012-07-24(f8f24ff2/d) [3m].
Language: racket.
> (list 'hi (list 'unquote 'there))
'(hi ,there)
```

Therefore the pattern you need is '(list h (list 'unquote t))'.

```
> (define s '(hi,there))
> (match s [(list h (list 'unquote t)) (list h t)])
(list 'hi 'there)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a backslash if you want to use comma as a symbol inside of a quoted section:

```
> (define s '(hi \, there))
> (match s [(list h c t) (symbol->string c)])
","
```

And use `'|,|` for the standalone comma symbol.

```
> (match s [(list h '|,| t) (list h t)])
'(hi there)
```

In either case, you really should use whitespace to separate things, and use lists.

`(define s (hi,there))` is not valid Racket.

Comment: The reason there is comma inside is that the file I am parsing uses it to separate a lot of things and I want to use Racket match to parse the file (actually more interested when I found comma is so special in Racket!) But thanks for the answers from you guys)

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be confused about where you need commas. In Racket, you do not use commas to separate elements in a list. Instead, you just use whitespace. Tell me if this is wrong, but what I imagine is that you are trying to match an expression like `(define s '(hi there))`. To do that, you would use

```
(match s
  [`(,h ,t) ...])
```

Then, in the area where the elipses is, the variable `h` has the value `'hi`, and the variable `t` has the value `'there`

Comment: I just want to take advantage of `match` in Racket to parse that s-expression-like format WITH COMMA inside of parenthesis.